# How to include one ecma into another in CQ component?

Tags: javascript, aem, sling

I'm trying to run some server-side ECMAScript in my CQ component.

Is there any way to include/import/require some other file (Underscore.js in fact) in my `/components/myComp/script.ecma`?

Answer (score 1):

I have note found any CQ documentation, but luckily I have found [Apache SLING-428](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-428), simply:

```
load("underscore.js");
```